# The Rebus Challenge

Tags: visual, rebus

A particularly easy Rebus. What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on how your keyboard is laid out:

> "Losing control" or "no alternative"

Answer (score 5):

It could be either

> damage control

or

> out of control / no control

Answer (score 4):

Based on my keyboard layout it is:

> "Lost control"

Comment: Yes.. I was looking for this exact phrase. Correct!

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be:

> "*Lack of Control*" or "*Lack of Alternative*"